# How to display if one column data is duplicate and I want to display in next row with other colums is null data. Need to prepare in OAS or query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oas

My current result:

| Column A | Column B | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | AB | col_amount |
| 01 | AB | col_amount |
| 01 | AB | col_amount |
| 02 | OA | col_amount |
| 03 | OE | col_amount |
| 03 | OE | col_amount |
| 04 | DB | col_amount |

I want to this output:

| Column A | Column B | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | AB | col_amount |
|  |  | col_amount |
|  |  | col_amount |
| 02 | OA | col_amount |
| 03 | OE | col_amount |
|  |  | col_amount |
| 04 | DB | col_amount |

Comment: How to set Serial No. (not include column A is null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have a client application that supports the `BREAK` command (which is not an SQL command but is a command for the SQL*Plus client or other similar clients) then you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT CASE a_rn WHEN 1 THEN column_a END AS column_a,
       CASE b_rn WHEN 1 THEN column_b END AS column_b,
       column_c
FROM   (
  SELECT column_a,
         column_b,
         column_c,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_a ORDER BY column_b, column_c)
           AS a_rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_a, column_b ORDER BY column_c)
           AS b_rn
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Column_A, Column_B, Column_C) AS
SELECT '01', 'AB', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01', 'AB', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01', 'AB', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02', 'OA', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03', 'OE', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03', 'OE', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '04', 'DB', 'col_amount' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | AB | col_amount |
| *null* | *null* | col_amount |
| *null* | *null* | col_amount |
| 02 | OA | col_amount |
| 03 | OE | col_amount |
| *null* | *null* | col_amount |
| 04 | DB | col_amount |

*Note: In Oracle, `NULL` and an empty string are identical.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rukeKJqZ)

Answer (score 0):

A simple option - if you use SQL*Plus - is `break` command.

Before:

```
SQL> select deptno, job, ename from emp order by deptno, job, ename;

    DEPTNO JOB       ENAME
---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLERK     MILLER
        10 MANAGER   CLARK
        10 PRESIDENT KING
        20 ANALYST   FORD
        20 ANALYST   SCOTT
        20 CLERK     ADAMS
        20 CLERK     SMITH
        20 MANAGER   JONES
        30 CLERK     JAMES
        30 MANAGER   BLAKE
        30 SALESMAN  ALLEN
        30 SALESMAN  MARTIN
        30 SALESMAN  TURNER
        30 SALESMAN  WARD

14 rows selected.
```

After:

```
SQL> break on deptno on job
SQL> select deptno, job, ename from emp order by deptno, job, ename;

    DEPTNO JOB       ENAME
---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLERK     MILLER
           MANAGER   CLARK
           PRESIDENT KING
        20 ANALYST   FORD
                     SCOTT
           CLERK     ADAMS
                     SMITH
           MANAGER   JONES
        30 CLERK     JAMES
           MANAGER   BLAKE
           SALESMAN  ALLEN
                     MARTIN
                     TURNER
                     WARD

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

If you don't use SQL*Plus, you can *simulate* `break` command with `lag` analytic function, e.g.

```
SQL> select
  2  case when deptno = lag(deptno) over (order by deptno, job, ename) then null
  3       else deptno
  4  end deptno,
  5  case when job = lag(job) over (order by deptno, job, ename) then null
  6       else job
  7  end job,
  8  ename
  9  from emp;

    DEPTNO JOB       ENAME
---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLERK     MILLER
           MANAGER   CLARK
           PRESIDENT KING
        20 ANALYST   FORD
                     SCOTT
           CLERK     ADAMS
                     SMITH
           MANAGER   JONES
        30 CLERK     JAMES
           MANAGER   BLAKE
           SALESMAN  ALLEN
                     MARTIN
                     TURNER
                     WARD

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Not in SQL*Plus, It is query in plsql for OAS report.

Comment: I'm not sure that your query works identically to `BREAK` - you want to use `PARTITION BY` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wMjcblms).

Comment: It is work when use in the fiddle example. Thanks